# Changing the color of the selected item in a UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with a black tint so the selected element is not visually different to the other elements as iOS darkens the selected item and hence black remains unchanged. Does anyone know how to make the selected element a lighter color/shade without using undocumented methods? I have successfully achieved this with a graduated layer but there must be an easier way!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an description how you can set an tintcolor for each segment.

http://www.framewreck.net/2010/07/custom-tintcolor-for-each-segment-of.html

Comment: The article says that this method uses only documented methods, but since UISegment is not documented, any method on that object must be undocumented also so I expect Apple would/could reject the app?